# How to format the WHERE clause and '?' in a SQLite query?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to use the built in SQLite functions and I'm not sure how to format a query. How do I format the `WHERE` clause and the `?` that can go in there:

```
column [] = {"name"};
selectionArg [] = {"john};
Select name from mytable where id = "john"

db.query(mytable, column, id = ?, selectionArg, null,null,null);
```

I'm not to where I can test it, but I'm trying to get it right the first time. I'm not sure if the `?` needs to be `"?"` or if it is `id = + "?"` and so forth. I can't seem to find any examples of the format.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For the query :

```
select name from mytable where id = "john"
```

use

```
(SQliteDatabase) db.query(
    "mytable" /* table */,
    new String[] { "name" } /* columns */,
    "id = ?" /* where or selection */,
    new String[] { "john" } /* selectionArgs i.e. value to replace ? */,
    null /* groupBy */,
    null /* having */,
    null /* orderBy */
);
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind I edited your answer as it is basically the better answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

You may not use quotes around the question marks

example:

```
db.query(
            true,
            "tablename",
            new String[] {
                "col1",
                "col2"
            },
            "col1 = ?",
            new String[]{ "value" },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
        );
```