# SQLite WHERE clause not working with VARCHAR

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, where-clause

```
mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer " + "  ( id INT(10) NOT NULL , name_surname VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL , card INT(10) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY(id) );");
mydb.execSQL("INSERT INTO customer (id, name_surname , card ) VALUES ('194', 'aaa' , '21' );");

Cursor cursor = ajcinemaDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name_surname=? " , new String[] {"aaa"});


    int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("id");
    int name_surnameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("name_surname");
    int cardColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("card");


    cursor.moveToFirst();


    if(cursor != null && (cursor.getCount() > 0)){

        do {


            String id = cursor.getString(idColumn);
            String name_surname = cursor.getString(name_surnameColumn);
            String card = cursor.getString(cardColumn);

            custinfo = custinfo  + card + "\n";


        }while(cursor.moveToNext());

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Results ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Why does this where clause return nothing ?

This specific clause works for id ( int ) , but not for name_surname( varchar ).

I've tried regular and raw query also, same results.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format the WHERE clause and '?' in a SQLite query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276099/how-to-format-the-where-clause-and-in-a-sqlite-query)

Comment: It is not duplicating, it is specifically about rawQuery and VARCHAR.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it is about VARCHAR. A query is a query and using the regular query method rather than rawQuery may yield the correct results

Comment: I tried with regular query, same results. Any ideas ?

Comment: Then your database doesn't really contain that record or you are not correctly reading the result from the cursor

Comment: In the "duplicate" post, they are also querying a VARCHAR, btw

Answer (score 0):

Try out following rawQuery statement:

1. `Cursor cursor = ajcinemaDB.rawQuery("SELECT id, name_surname, card  FROM customer WHERE name_surname=? " , new String[] {"aaa"});`
2. `Cursor cursor = ajcinemaDB.rawQuery("SELECT *  FROM customer WHERE name_surname='aaa'",null);`

Comment: Thank you, although this is irrelevant. Apparently the problem was a database schema change that went unnoticed.