# Select Where with SQLite and android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hey i currently have two functions one that prints the entire database as a string and another that is supposed to only get the data when a criteria is met within the "TODO" column of the database, these are as follows.

```
     public String databaseToString() {
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LIST + " WHERE 1";

    //Cursor points to a location in your results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //Move to the first row in your results
    c.moveToFirst();

    //Position after the last row means the end of the results
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ToDo")) != null) {
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ToDo"));
            dbString += " ";
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("accFor"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
```

This is the code for the working function that turns the entire database into a string to be printed. Below is the none working function that is supposed to get all values from the database where TODO is equal to the string university which i have called further up in mydatabasemanager app that contains both of these functions

```
 public String UniversityToString() {
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = ("SELECT " + COLUMN_TODO + COLUMN_FOR + " FROM " + TABLE_LIST + " WHERE "+ COLUMN_FOR + "=\"" + University + "\";");

    //Cursor points to a location in your results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //Move to the first row in your results
    c.moveToFirst();

    //Position after the last row means the end of the results
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ToDo")) != null) {
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ToDo"));
            dbString += " ";
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("accFor"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }

    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
```

This code here causes my app to crash upon opening the activity that calls it i am just wondering how i would fix this to correctly select the data that i require.

Comment: attach the error with stackttrace

Comment: String concatenation is error prone. You could look at this question for a cleaner way to query the database.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276099/how-to-format-the-where-clause-and-in-a-sqlite-query

Comment: @ cricket_007

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kai.todolist/com.kai.todolist.Main3Activity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: University (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT ToDo, accFor FROM List WHERE accFor=University

Comment: instead of dealing with sqlite directly why not use an orm to simplify and speed up your development! I use https://realm.io/

Answer (score 0):

There should at least be something between the two columns in your query.

```
COLUMN_TODO + ", " COLUMN_FOR
```

You also don't need to add the ; at the end of the querystring