# Query is not returning any data SQLite

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite

I have database with 4 columns int id | String data | String date | int boot and i have some data in it. I have method getRow(String s) when i call it with string for id or data and change query to that option it works but when i´m trying to get row with equal date it won´t pass cursor.moveToFirst condition.

Here is my code:

```
String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_DATA
            + " TEXT," + COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT," + COLUMN_BOOT + " Integer" + ")";


 public String getRowID(String id){
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
     if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
         //loggin succes
         return "string";
     }else return null;
 }

 public String getRowDate(String date){
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + COLUMN_DATE + " = " + date, null);
     if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
         //loggin succes
         return "string";
     }else return null;
 }

myDb.getRowID("1"); returning something
myDb.getRowDate("02122016"); returning null
```

I have two rows in my database.

```
1 | 0.19 | 01122016 | 0
2 | 0.19 | 02122016 | 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be wary when comparing integers and strings. You may wonder why SQLite would be comparing integers at all since your arguments are strings, until you consider that your raw query looks like this:

```
select * from TABLE where DATE = 02122016
```

That value is interpreted as an integer and converted to text, but it loses the leading zero in the process. You can verify this with a sqlite3 shell:

```
sqlite> select 02122016;
2122016
sqlite> select '02122016' = 02122016;
0 -- false
sqlite> select cast(02122016 as text);
2122016
```

The simplest fix is to quote the value using a method from [`DatabaseUtils`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#sqlEscapeString(java.lang.String)):

```
String escaped = DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(date);
String query = "select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + COLUMN_DATE + " = " + escaped;
```

A better fix would be to use a placeholder argument instead. Note that Android binds all arguments as strings:

```
String query = "select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " where " + COLUMN_DATE + " = ?";
db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{date});
```

However, my advice would be to not use `rawQuery()` and instead use one of the real [`query()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) methods. [Here's a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5276236/1207921).

Lastly, perhaps you should consider a different format for storing dates. In practice I usually either store an INTEGER column with a unix timestamp (seconds or milliseconds since epoch), or I use a TEXT column with values in the `yyyy-MM-dd` format since this is implicitly supported by numerous datetime functions in SQLite.

Comment: Great answer with a lot of examples and ways to solve my problem. Thanks